# What's causing my hard disk's activity?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have a set of external hard disks I'm using for backups, so except for the backup in the middle of the night they shouldn't show any activity. Now on one of the drives the LED has been blinking for hours, indicating some activity.

Is there a way to find which program/process is accessing the drive?

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. Open Resource Monitor from Windows Task Manager's Performance tab and go to Disk tab. You can simply type "resource monitor" in the start menu also.

Under the Disk tab all the processes with disk activity are listed down along with their PID and read/write speed. You can kill a process from there directly by right clicking it and then End Process or End Process Tree.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately when you click a disk in the storage pane it doesn't seem to filter the processes that use this disk. (Correct?)

Comment: The processes are listed in the "Processes with Disk Activity" section. The "Storage" section only gives you a summary of all the different storage devices that are attached with your computer.